# Impossible to remove page from menu

Tags: menus

I’m facing problem with my site www.engliscare.net
The site is running on Divi and I’m not able to remove any page from menu. It appears automatically there and if I try to edit it from appearance - menu it is not there. It’s empty.
Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Thank you for your time and experiences!

Comment: most likely this is the fallback menu based on your pages - try creating an actual custom menu with whatever pages you want. please continue this question with the support forum of your theme.

Comment: It worked. I’ve opened the visual builder and edited through that. It didn’t work before. Dunno what was wrong. Thank you!